# TypeScript index types constraint with "callback type" works incorrectly?

Tags: typescript

I can't understand why this will give me an error (with compiler option `"strict": true`).

```
class EventX {
  public type: string

  constructor(type: string) {
    this.type = type
  }
}

class ClickEvent extends EventX {
  public x: number

  constructor(type: string, x: number) {
    super(type);
    this.x = x;
  }
}

interface Events {
  [eventType: string]: (event: EventX) => any

  click: (e: ClickEvent) => any  // TS2411: Property 'click' of type '(e: ClickEvent) => any' is not assignable to string index type '(event: EventX) => any'.
}
```

By the way this works fine

```
interface Events {
  [eventType: string]: EventX

  click: ClickEvent
}
```

So I think is this part `(event: EventX) => any` cause the problem. But what's wrong with this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that an index signature must include all possible types that the values may have:

```
interface Events {
    click: (event: ClickEvent) => any;
    [eventType: string]: ((event: EventX) => any) | ((event: ClickEvent) => any);
}
```

This is due to ALL keys being included in the index signature `[x: string]`, thus all are checked for conformance - and since (event: ClickEvent) => any is not assignable to (event: EventX) => any it throws an error

Edit: Mihályi Zoltán has a better explanation.

Comment: The `ClickEvent` extends the `EventX` class, I can't understand why it is "not assignable to `(event: EventX) => any`"...

Comment: The thing is that, as Mihályi Zoltán explained, `events['click' as string](new EventX())` would be correct at compile-time (TS checks) but potentially incorrect at run-time (e.g. the function getting `undefined` for `event.x`)

Comment: Thanks! @Elias Schablowski well that is interesting... but I think no one will write such stupid code anyway. so TypeScript ONLY checks against functions? Is this is intended or a bug??

Comment: @yaquawa, this applies to objects as well, although as Mihályi Zoltán pointed out, `events['click' as string] = new EventX()` is technically valid it really shouldn't be. But TypeScript mostly checks against accessing rather than inserting. And this code may come in when iterating over all keys, or other such tasks.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two examples is "variance".

In the second example `events['click' as string]` is just an EventX, which is OK.
But in the first example `events['click' as string](new EventX())` should cause an error, and the TypeScript error prevents this.

Edit:
Don't ask me why `events['click' as string] = new EventX()` is not prevented by TypeScript as it does for functions